# Can't create an instance of Attribute for a unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, constructor, mocking

I am using an API that has a method that fetches some data from a remote server. The method usage is like this:

```java
Attribute a = obj.getRemoteAttribute();
```

The `Attribute` class is like this

```java
package a.package.outside.my.project;

import java.util.Date;

public class Attribute {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private Date modifiedAt;
  private String metadata;

  Attribute(String id, String name, Date modifiedAt, String metadata) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.modifiedAt = modifiedAt;
    this.metadata = metadata;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public Date getModifiedAt() {
    return modifiedAt;
  }

  public String getMetadata() {
    return metadata;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a unit test, mocking this method. I'm with `Mockito` for that. The test is something like this:

```java
    @Test
    public void getAttributeShouldWork() throws Exception {
        Storage mockStorage = Mockito.mock(Storage.class);
        Attribute attribute = new Attribute("fake", "fakeName", new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("21/08/2019"), "fake Metadata"); 
        Mockito.when(storage.getAttribute()).thenReturn(attribute);
        // some other stuff
    }
```

However, the test does not compile - the constructor from `Attribute` (4º line) is package private and I can't use it in the test. I can't also extend the class - there is no default constructor. There is no factory to create `Attribute`, no accessible builder class. I also can't change `Attribute`'s code.

So, my question is - how can I create a fake object to use in this test with mocks? I don't want my unit tests depending on network or remote server's availability...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a pinch, you could use reflection:

```
private static Attribute createAttributeStub() {
    try {
        Constructor<Attribute> constructor = 
                Attribute.class.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, String.class, 
                        Date.class, String.class);
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        return constructor.newInstance("fake", "fakeName", 
                new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("21/08/2019"), "fake Metadata");
    }
    catch( ReflectiveOperationException | ParseException e ) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```